# CSS not loading anyhow

Tags: html, css, node.js, ubuntu, phpstorm

I am working over the node server using PhpStorm in Ubuntu. Everything works fine except the CSS part. It is not loading anyhow. I manually opened the site but the CSS part was not there. I tried to open it over Django server using PyCharm but no use.

I created a sample site with the external CSS link but there also it was not loading. I just can't figure out where the issue is.

I am using HTML5 boilerplate with default pages given in PhpStorm.

File hierarchy is as follows:

```
Website
 -css
   -main.css
   -normalize.css
   -custom.css
 -index.html
```

CSS Link

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WebAPP</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!--Local CSS-->
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<meta property="og:title" content>
<meta property="og:type" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="">

<link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
<!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

<!--Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">

</head>
```

Here is the error from browser's network panel

```
The resource at “<URL>” was blocked because content blocking is enabled. 2
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/custom.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/normalize.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/main.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js”. WebApp:35:1
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/plugins.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/plugins.js”. WebApp:36:1
GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/main.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 6ms]

The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/js/main.js”. WebApp:37:1
GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/icon.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/custom.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/normalize.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
WebApp
The resource from “http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/main.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Comment: It was a mistake the folder is in Small 'css'

Comment: Check how requests to those URLs look in your browser's Network Panel: what HTTP error code it reports, what path is requested etc etc.

Comment: i have updated the error from browser's network panel

Comment: Well .. you have the answer there: *“http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/custom.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).* Your web server sends `text/html` in `Content-Type` response header instead of expected `text/css`. and `X-Content-Type-Options` header disallows browser to fix that (which is a good thing, as it prevents vulnerabilities). **You need to fix your web server config.**

Comment: And you have exactly the same issue with `.js` files. So you need to look into your node.js script/web server (as I understand from your description it is the one that serves those files).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks man, you're a life saver. I wanted to but I am not able to upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `“http://127.0.0.1:8000/WebApp/css/custom.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

You have the answer right there: your web server sends `text/html` in `Content-Type` response header instead of expected `text/css` and `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header disallows browser to auto-fix that (which is a good thing, as it prevents vulnerabilities: better detect and fix it now in dev environment than have possible issues later in production).

And you have exactly the same issue with `.js` files.

**You need to fix your web server config**. It must be node.js powered code that serves those files (as far I understand from your description).

Comment: I had to edit my lite-server ```config.json``` file by altering the ```content-type``` to ```text/css```. In Django server also the same workaround fixes the problem. I would update more as soon as I get fixes for other platforms as it was a common issue in most of the places

Comment: In Django use of static files removes this problem. We just need to make a static folder and put our CSS, JavaScript, Bootstrap and Image folder there. The base HTML should be configured to load static folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to load CSS in Uppercase Address.

```
  <!--Local CSS-->
  <link href="CSS/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="CSS/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Sorry, it is in small 'css', I mistakenly typed in Caps

Comment: Actually when I write the wrong css address. It show with an error message in the browser. I think the browser detects it but css changes doesn't appear. Not even a single code

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the CSS path defining the current directory:

```
<!--Local CSS-->
<link href="./css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```